# Do islam support pedophelia?

Tags: nikah, prophet-muhammad

Recently one of my friend asked a question to me related to the stand and opinion of pedophelia in islam in connection wit te marriage of prophet Muhammed(S. A) and Ayrsha (R. A).  Prophet married Ayesha who was 9(? ) years old at that time. How it is analysed?

Comment: Pedophelia as a crime is something new and came out centuries after the spread of Islam.

Comment: Related questions: [here](https://islam.stackexchange.com/a/12365/17702) and [here](https://islam.stackexchange.com/a/22999/17702) (which acknowledges the validity of child marriages in Islam and makes excuses for that) and [here](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/39155/17702) (related since children - apart from not being in a developmental position to take a firm stance against being married off - do not even have the legal right to object according to many scholars) and perhaps [here](https://islam.stackexchange.com/a/39130/17702). Child marriage is halal, so pedophilia is too.

Answer (score 0):

Though Muslims would not call it pedophilia, the law in most countries is so. Muslims are instructed to lived according to the example set worth by Mohammed (which is recorded in documents called Hadith's) and indeed Mohammed consummated the marriage of his wife Aisha when she was 9 years old.

In Islam, it is not pedophilia if a child has had their first period.